# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function UNION ALL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two queries that use the `SUBSTRING` function within a `CASE` statement like so:

```
CASE
    WHEN Answer.ChoiceTitle = 'Neither Likely or Unlikely'
        THEN 'Neither Likely nor Unlikely'
    WHEN Answer.ChoiceTitle LIKE '[1-5]%'
        THEN SUBSTRING(Answer.ChoiceTitle, 3, LEN(Answer.ChoiceTitle) - 2)
    ELSE Answer.ChoiceTitle
END AS Recommendation
```

Both queries run perfectly fine when run separately but when I try to combine both result sets with a `UNION ALL` I get the error message:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Whilst trying to figure out why this error is occurring I added the below to each statement and the `UNION ALL` now works perfectly fine.

```
MIN(LEN(Answer.ChoiceTitle)) OVER() AS MinLength
```

Why would I be getting this error?

**Execution Plans**

Planned Execution Plan with `UNION ALL` -  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rksFnuLS-

Actual Execution Plan of first statement - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1Z-pO8HW

Actual Execution Plan of second statement - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkCTh_IBb

Comment: you need to make sure your `SUBSTRING` could take up to `LEN(Answer.ChoiceTitle) - 2` from start position 3

Comment: Yes it can, `Answer.ChoiceTitle` is datatype `VARCHAR(8000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely causing your error: `LEN(Answer.ChoiceTitle) - 2`

When that evaluates to less than 0, it will throw an error.

Try this instead:

```
CASE
    WHEN Answer.ChoiceTitle = 'Neither Likely or Unlikely'
        THEN 'Neither Likely nor Unlikely'
    WHEN Answer.ChoiceTitle LIKE '[1-5]%' and LEN(Answer.ChoiceTitle) > 2
        THEN SUBSTRING(Answer.ChoiceTitle, 3, LEN(Answer.ChoiceTitle) - 2)
    ELSE Answer.ChoiceTitle
END AS Recommendation
```

---

Since you are just getting rid of the first two characters, you could use `stuff()` instead like so:

```
CASE
    WHEN Answer.ChoiceTitle = 'Neither Likely or Unlikely'
        THEN 'Neither Likely nor Unlikely'
    WHEN Answer.ChoiceTitle LIKE '[1-5]%'
        THEN stuff(Answer.ChoiceTitle,1,2,'')
    ELSE Answer.ChoiceTitle
END AS Recommendation
```

This will give you an empty string if the length is less than 3, otherwise it will remove the first two characters of `Answer.ChoiceTitle`.

---

As to why the combined query with `union all` throws an error when the others run alone do not:

I'm seeing this difference in the execution plans:

```
Hash Match > (Question & Survey nested loop) & (Compute Scalar > Answer) {Bottom right of execution plan without error}
vs
Hash Match > (Bitmap > Parallelism > Question) & (Compute Scalar > Answer) {Bottom right of execution plan with error}
```

the nested loop version may be filtering rows that cause the error prior to the hash match, thus avoiding the error.

It is possible that using `option (maxdop 1)` to prevent parallelism would avoid the error as well (confirmed) on the query that is currently throwing it
this just comes down to when the scalar function is being evaluated for the rows in the answer table, pre or post filtering out the rows you want to run the expression on.

The cost is higher in the `union all` version, and it exceeds the cost threshold for parallelism, which is why you wouldn't see the same error when run alone where it does not go parallel (specifically parallel in the same way) with the lower cost when run alone.

So basically the parallel plan is running the substring() sooner than your other plans, before the rows that throw errors are filtered out.

Comment: `LEN(Answer.ChoiceTitle) - 2` does not evaluate to less than 0 on all data rows, the lowest value is 6. If this was the case then surely one of the queries would error when run independently?

Comment: @mheptinstall See if you have the same issue if you use `stuff()` instead. If so, something else may be causing the error.

Comment: Using `STUFF` works and every row contains a value there are no empty strings or NULLs. Still doesn't explain why `SUBSTRING` doesn't work in the `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @mheptinstall Can you post the execution plan for the query that throws the error? Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: @mheptinstall Are you using views in your query that might be expanded by the execution plan to the base tables, and might those tables include rows that could cause this error that should otherwise be filtered out by the views?

Comment: Everything is against base tables and I use a CTE in my query. I can only provide a planned execution plan, I can't get the actual because the query fails. Or can provide actual execution plans for each statement separately without the `UNION ALL`

Comment: @mheptinstall estimated execution plan should be fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149250/discussion-between-sqlzim-and-mheptinstall).